# Underscore permeates

Tags: css

I want to add a colored underscore to my title, now everything works, but when there is a word in brackets in the title, this underline is interrupted. Can I somehow do so that it is not interrupted under any circumstances?

```css
.title {
  text-decoration: underline 8px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">some title (zwe)</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border-bottom` instead

```css
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 8px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">some title (zwe)</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```css
.title {
  text-decoration: underline 8px solid blue;
  text-underline-position: under;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">some title (zwe)</h2>
```